# Bitmap class error in c# (The parameter is not valid)

Tags: c#, bitmap

I want to convert an image to bitmap format. Here's the code i wrote :-

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("c:\\images\\a10.png");
```

The parameter image is taken from the function parameter. It takes a full path with filename. When i run, an error pops up showing "The parameter is not valid". But this class accepts filename as constructor.

Comment: Is `image` a System.Drawing.Image?

Comment: @paqogomez No it is just a string variable, that accepts a fully qualified path with filename.

Comment: GDI+ exceptions are not very good.  It can mean several things: bad filename, bad file content, file inaccessible or doesn't fit in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The image path you set is not correct.  That image does not exist at that location.

Check your path to verify the image.

This code will properly save a png to a bmp provided the png exists.

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("c:\\images\\a10.png");
bmp.Save("c:\\images\\a10.bmp");
```

EDIT:

The above worked for me, but here is another way:

```
Image bmp = Image.FromFile("c:\\images\\a10.png");
bmp.Save("c:\\images\\a10.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Comment: That Save() call actually saves the image in the PNG format, the default format if you don't explicitly specify the image format.  It does *not* pay attention to the filename extension.  So your code leaves a .bmp file behind that is not actually a BMP file.  Pretty bad idea.

Comment: @HansPassant I thought so too until I tried it.  Did it myself, and it saved a bitmap.

Comment: I used .Net 4.5.  @Sandesh, HansPassant is correct, there must be something wrong w/ that file you are trying to load.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way ever is:

```
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap("C:/images/a10.png");
```